# How to set up Commerce 2.x VAT

Tags: commerce

How to use Taxes on Commerce 2.x ?
I created a Tax Type (European Union VAT), enabled it in the store, but no tax is applied.
It seems that all issues regarding tax module development are closed, so I don't understand.

Comment: https://www.flocondetoile.fr/blog/apply-vat-rate-product-drupal-commerce-2

Comment: Thanks Bojan, So there is no UI developped yet ? I was expecting a simpler way for my clients, they need to have product-specific taxes. I'll try to make a tax reference field on the product.

Comment: Furthermore, even the default tax is not applied in my case. Am I missing something ?